# Moving document windows to a particular screen and location

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have two monitors, one landscape orientation and one portrait and like to view text documents in portrait orientation. This means that every time I open a document I have to drag it to the correct monitor, position it then drag it out to fill the screen. Very tedious when repeated many times a day.

Is there a command or script that can be used to do this for me? I'm hoping for a Finder droplet that I can drag a document too that will move it to the portrait orientation monitor and zoom it out to the whole screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're opening documents in the same app you can force that app to one screen by right-clicking on it in the dock, and under options, picking the screen you want under the "Assign to" section at the bottom.

If you use screens you can pick which screen on which monitor as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm surprised I never noticed that feature before!

Comment: I've found your solution works most of the time tho as I move between a laptop with two monitors attached to just the laptop I sometimes find the setting doesn't stick (altho still ticked) but after a while it will start working again. I've given this some time for other answers but none have shown up so yours gets the tick.